# php: file_exists error with comma AND space

Tags: php, file-exists

I've configured a file download, but in some cases files can't be downloaded.
Because the file_exist isn't true, the php code dies and gives me back the defined error message.

Why does the download work fine with a **comma** **OR** **space** in the directory, 
but fails with **BOTH** a **comma** followed with a **space**?

The file with download error:

```
$the_download = "/share/Multimedia/Library1/John, Doe/test/cover.jpg";
```

The files that download ok:

```
$the_download = "/share/Multimedia/Library1/John,Doe/test/cover.jpg";
$the_download = "/share/Multimedia/Library1/John Doe/test/cover.jpg";
```

code:

```
$the_filename = "somefilename.jpg";

    if (file_exists($the_download)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($the_filename));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($the_download));
        flush();
        readfile($the_download);
        exit;
    }
    else die("File not found<br>" . $the_download);
```

Comment: What error message ?

Comment: Error message: File not found 35, as in the else die statement. The script dies and shows me the filename. The filename is perfectly fine when I look it up locally within " "

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the filename in the header with double quotes like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($the_filename).'"');
```

Comment: It's not about this line (I think).
This line is just for chaning the filename the downloader receives, which is fine. It's the file that can't be found, which is in error and it dies. I've added that variable $the_filename now in to the code. Perhaps I could leave out the whole download part, and just leave it with the file_exists check only)

Comment: The reason that didn't work was probably a mistake in the code. I fixed the syntax error